Is there any gradle plugin for checking versions of transitive dependency?
We have a modular project and dependency looks like this
core
level_1-app depends on core
level_2-app depends on level_1-app
level_3_1-app depends on level_2-app
level_3_2-app depends on level_2-app
level_3_3-app depends on level_2-app
level_3_4-app depends on level_2-app
facade-app depends on level_3_1-app, level_3_2-app, level_3_3-app, level_3_4-app

We still don't have any semver versioning for modules so currently we decided that transitive versions should be always the same for all projects(I mean only our projects. For other libraries we don't want to have such kinda of restriction).
On facade-app we want to check that all transitive dependencies have the same version of core, level_1-app and level_2-app. And if it is not - build should fail or at least warn.
Is there any gradle plugin that could do it or should we implement our own?

Will the Gradle dependency cosntraints feature not help? - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_constraints.html#sec:adding-constraints-transitive-deps

This isn't perfect, but this is roughly how I'd approach it
// In facade-app's build.gradle

def enforcedModules = ['core', 'level_1-app', 'level_2-app']
def moduleVersions = [:]

configurations.all { config ->
    // Check only resolvable configurations
    if (config.canBeResolved) {
        config.incoming.afterResolve { resolvableDependencies ->
            resolvableDependencies.resolutionResult.allDependencies { dep ->
                def selectedId = dep.selected.id
                // Ensure we have a module dependency
                if (selectedId instanceof ModuleComponentIdentifier) {
                    def moduleName = selectedId.module
                    if (enforcedModules.contains(moduleName)) {
                        def version = selectedId.version
                        if (!moduleVersions.containsKey(moduleName)) {
                            // Store the version if encountering the module for the first time
                            moduleVersions[moduleName] = version
                        } else if (moduleVersions[moduleName] != version) {
                            // Fail the build if a version mismatch is detected
                            throw new GradleException("Version mismatch detected for '${moduleName}'. Versions used: '${moduleVersions[moduleName]}' and '${version}'")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


def moduleVersions = [:]

Is it a pseudocode of empty array ?

That should be valid groovy, it initializes an empty map (dictionary)
